# Why does the Templar awareness meter background stay red?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

Sometimes in this game I'm just running around as a garden variety cold blooded mass murderer, but sometimes I commit the unspeakable crime of...  *purchasing property*‽

I frequently find myself at max Templar Awareness, which causes the meter to have a red flashing background.  If I do something to reduce it somewhat (bribing a witness or assassinating a herald...  wait, I might have that backwards... sorry heralds :( ), the background of the meter stays red.  If I can manage to bottom it completely out, it goes back to black, however.

So to summarize:

- at 100%, the meter is flashing red
- Once it's been to 100%, but before I do enough to make it 0%, the background stays red but stops flashing.
- At 0%, the background goes back to black, and stays that way regardless of my awareness, until I hit 100% again.

Is there anything different about the second state versus the third?  Should I be completely eliminating my awareness any time it hits the max in order to avoid some penalty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the background is red but not flashing, your assassin dens are at risk of being invaded by templars.  Personally, I found the den defense mini-game to be quite annoying.  As such, I tried to always keep my templar awareness at "anonymous," which is the third state you described.  All you need to do is assassinate a few officials and/or bribe a few heralds; I considered that a small price to pay to avoid den defense missions

Comment: Though you have to be pretty high on that meter just to be able to assassinate the officials. The heralds got rich off of me as a result.

Comment: @JeffMercado True, although if you continually try to clear your awareness right whenever it hits the top of the charts, then you won't have an issue.  I didn't have many issues clearing my meter

Comment: Me neither, just kinda annoying that for the most part, the heralds were the _only_ option.

Comment: Ugh, this is what I was afraid of.  I hate the awareness system in this game with a passion.

Comment: @agent86: Don't worry, once you get your 7 Master Assassins, you will be completely immune to the Templar Awareness.

Comment: I got my 3 den defenses done in act 3 then got master ranks into all my dens.

Comment: can you rip posters down in revelations, or is it just heralds/officials? in the last 2 games i just ripped down a few posters whenever i got above 25% notoriety

Comment: @Kip There are no posters in Revelations, sadly.  The only way to remove notoriety is heralds and officials